# Draw a circle on top of contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure with pyplot.contour and another figure with peplos.contourf.

I am trying to add a circle to these figures, so I used:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
circle = Circle((3, 5), 0.5, color='b', alpha=0.3)
pyplot.figure.add_patch(circle)
```

However, it seems that it does not work. It throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'add_patch'"
```

Do you have any ideas on how we can plot a circle on top of contour plot?
Thank you

Comment: `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` and `plt.gca().add_patch(circle)` might help. Note that your post is missing imports and information about how you created the `contourf` plot.

Comment: Your error is telling you pyplot.figure is a function--you would use it like `fig = pyplot.figure()`. In this case, though,you want the Axes object like Johan describes.